# how to delete a key from mongoid hash field

Tags: mongoid5, mongoid6

I have a hash field in Mongoid document like `< _id: 58a202d407953817ece2989c, d: {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d"}>` i want to pop key `a` from it so that hash filed contain only `c` how to do this in mongoid?

Answer (score 0):

if we consider
`data = ..., d: {"a"=>"b", "c"=>"d"}, ...`
then
`data.d.delete("a")`